# Symfony2 Assetic cssrewrite making bad links

Tags: css, symfony, assetic

I have some css files that are being combined into a single css file by assetic.  They have some references to image assets that are being rewritten by cssrewrite.  Cssrewrite is clearly making completely wrong links.

Folder structure:

```
-src
   -Project
      -StoreBundle
         -public
            -images
               -store
                  -v2
                    -logo.svg
            -css
               -store
                  -v2
                    -font.css
                    -html5reset.css
                    -store.css
```

I have the following settings for assetic in config.yml:

```
store_web_css:
    inputs:
        - '@ProjectStoreBundle/Resources/public/css/store/v2/html5reset.css'
        - '@ProjectStoreBundle/Resources/public/css/store/v2/font.css'
        - '@ProjectStoreBundle/Resources/public/css/store/v2/store.css'
    filters:
        - ?yui_css
        - cssembed
        - cssrewrite
    output: css/store.web.css
```

Assetic has setting such that the images are getting written to `/web/bundles/projectstore/images/store/v2/` whereas the combined css files (store.web.css) gets written `/web/css/store'

There is the following link in the css file:

```
url('../bundles/projectstore/images/store/v2/logo.svg');
```

that becomes this in /web/css/store.web.css:

```
url(../Resources/public/css/store/bundles/pokkistore/images/store/v2/logo.svg);
```

I've read in other threads that there's a bug with the cssrewrite filter using the @ style of referencing to the css files, but the links to logo.svg and other assets are still broken even if I try to change them.

Assetic has write_to set to "web/store", no settings for read_from.

Comment: Try setting up symlinks with assetic.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to** use the `bundles/projectstore` notation instead of `@ProjectStoreBundle/Resources/public` notation as [stated in the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html):

> you referred to the CSS files using their actual, publicly-accessible path: bundles/app/css. You can use either, except that there is a known issue that causes the cssrewrite filter to fail when using the @AppBundle syntax for CSS Stylesheets.

**And** use relative paths to where your stylesheet is at the moment you write it, not to where it'll be once  processed by Assetic:

```
url('../bundles/projectstore/images/store/v2/logo.svg');
```

is wrong, it should have a relative path to the asset, like:

```
url('logo.svg');
```

if they both are in the same directory. Or in your case:

```
url('../../../images/store/v2/logo.svg');
```

Comment: As I said, I tried using the non @ style, but the links are still wrong.  Example, I referenced the css files of the pattern `bundles/projectstore/css/store/v2/html5reset.css` instead in config.yml, and then in store.web.css the links ended up like `../bundles/pokkistore/css/store/bundles/pokkistore/images/store/v2/logo.svg` which is still very much incorrect.

Comment: @Kai That's very much correct and it's the expected behaviour for Assetic. Your CSS should have a relative reference to where they are not to where Assetic will maybe put the compiled stylesheet. You need to change your CSS as edited in the answer.

Comment: I tried change the urls in the css file as you said as well -- example: `background-image: url('../../../images/store/v2/logo.svg');`, but it is still resulting in the same incorrect line in the compiled css `background-image:url(../bundles/pokkistore/css/store/bundles/pokkistore/images/store/v2/logo.svg);`

Comment: That doesn't make sense, sounds like a cache issue or the assets are hard copied instead of symlinked because that did non change at all and it should have. Have you run in order `app/console assets:install --symlink` and `app/console cache:clear`?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change output to match your path:

like...

{% stylesheets '@DefaultBundle/Resources/public/css/screen-normalize.css' output='/bundles/default/css/main.css' %}